# Is it safe to allow multiple Firebase accounts with the same email address?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working to add Firebase authentication to a web app using "federated" providers, i.e. Google, Facebook, etc.

I immediately discovered the limitation of the default setting, "one account per email address."  Right away users who have the same email for Google and Facebook, for instance, can only use one or the other, not both.

[The Firebase help page](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400716) warns me: "If you do allow multiple accounts with the same email address, your app's sign-in flow cannot rely on an email address to identify a user account."

I can't figure out whether that's something I need to worry about.  The alternative appears to be very spaghetti-like code to snarf the second provider's credentials and then stuff it into the first provider's credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Allowing the user to sign in with the same email address from either their Facebook or Google account is a powerful feature called [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).

If you find it tricky to get account linking (or other flows related to sign-in) working, I recommend looking into using FirebaseUI, which comes in [web](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web), [iOS](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-ios) and [Android](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android) flavors and handles those flows for you.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out whether solving it by just allowing multiple accounts for the same email will be problematic.  It seems like the system is already susceptible to two accounts for the same user, if, say, that user uses different emails on FB and Google.  The system will never detect that it's the same person using the two different auth providers, will it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm discovering this a tricky problem.

Firebase has two modes:

1. `allow multiple accounts per email:TRUE` -- enable this and you can log-in with both Facebook and Gmail, however they will not send you the user's email, they will only send gmail.uid and facebook.uid and there is no way to know they are related
2. `allow multiple accounts per email:FALSE` -- firebase sends you email info, but you cannot login with facebook if you logged in with google (because facebook is an 'untrusted provider') -- so why even display the button?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be one other "gotcha" related to this setting. I first started out having the setting disabled, since I only offered Google sign in anyway.

A few months (and a few thousand registered users) went by and I implemented more sign in methods and decided to enable the setting, letting users sign in with the same email from multiple providers without linking them.

However, now it appears that when signing in with the same Google account as before, the `uid` is different from what it was when the setting was disabled. This resulted in users settings being reset, since my backend relied on the `uid` from Firebase to identify the user.

So you'd better be aware of this, and perhaps plan some way to detect this and update the `uid` on your backend, perhaps by looking up the `uid` from the provider data (which is the same for the same Google account, no matter what the setting is).